# How to extend raster data for larger boundary?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1

I am working on serveral raster data, but some of them are not fill data exactly with intended boundary (as shown in the picture below). What i want to do is firstly extend the raster data to intended boundary (pink line).

Can you help me with this problem?

[image: Raster data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool I would use is [Euclidean Allocation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000001m000000), this will 'stretch' out your values based on the existing closest value (not changing any existing values), then use [Extract by Mask](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Extract_by_Mask/009z0000002n000000/) to get the area that's just within the extent to keep it neat.

The Euclidean Allocation tool (spatial analyst required) **only works with integer rasters**, if you have floating point data (with decimals) you will need to multiply by a scale factor ([Times tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Times/009z0000009p000000/)), convert to an integer (use [Int](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Int/009z0000008z000000/)) and then divide by the same scale factor to return it to a floating point value ([divide tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Divide/009z0000008r000000/)), this will of course round the values but it's better than nothing.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is exactly what i want to solve my problems!