# Fill raster to shapefile boundary

Tags: raster, arcmap, boundaries

I created TIN from contour lines, then I convert this TIN to Raster.
After that I clipped the raster by `Extract by Mask` tool,
now the problem is raster does not fill whole boundary.

Below image show the problem, how can I figure out this?

[image]

Comment: It looks like your source data was incomplete. The mask function isn't going to add data, just remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I just had to do this myself. I followed another post as guidance [How to extend raster data for larger boundary?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150942/how-to-extend-raster-data-for-larger-boundary#)

What you're looking for is a Euclidean Allocation. 
Make sure you specify the shapefile boundary in the processing extent.

Comment: I used `Topo to Raster` instead of the above method
and the output raster was coincident to boundary